# How do I break the yellow block surrounded by grey blocks in World 3-1?

Tags: paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door

In the third and last Bowser stage (World 3-1) of *Paper Mario: The Thousand-Year Door*, there is a yellow block that is surrounded by unbreakable grey blocks and seems to be impossible to break.

If Bowser is large or huge, he still cannot break the grey blocks protecting the yellow one, and his flame-breath does not reach the yellow block.

If Bowser is small enough to fit under the grey-block shield, his flame-breath is too weak to break it, and there is not enough room to jump on it.

(To be clear, I have tried all of the sizes that Bowser can be.)

What the heck is in that block and how do you break it‽

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Get large after eating the first meat.
2. Destroy the X-Naut so you can feel safe (however, you aren't necessarily safe)
3. Go to the left of the yellow block, so you can see the whole block in your screen.
4. Then go to the bottom-right side very very slowly, so you can see much more of the yellow block.
5. Finally fire to destroy the yellow block!

Comment: Like I [already said](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17423/#comment27607_19793), it doesn’t work because his fire-breath doesn’t reach the block. Have you actually tried this or are you just guessing? If so, then what was in it?

Answer (score 3):

Not having the game myself, I couldn't test this, but I think I figured out how to get it.

I read a whole bunch of walkthroughs and watched LP's but everyone just skips that block. I think if you go past the gray blocks with Bowser as big as you can get him, then turn around and breathe fire it should destroy the yellow block. There's a hammer guy immediately after this that you would then take damage from (or the fire stick I guess) to get really small.

Whatever the object is would fall into the lava, but (from one of the LPs I watched anyway) the item sits on top of the lava. You should be able to drop, grab the item, then jump back up before hitting the lava.

Comment: Well it's not possible from the left; his breath doesn't reach, but maybe there is enough room on the other side for Bowser to sit at the same level. I'll give it a try when I can get my GameCube out (I have a saved game at that point specifically for this purpose. `;-)`)

Comment: Don't forget to let us know what the item is, if you get it!

Comment: @Synetech inc. - Yep, that's exactly what I meant. It's the only thing I can figure without having the game myself to try it.

Comment: Nope sorry. When Bowser is huge and goes to the right of the yellow block, the block is not on screen and thus cannot be broken with the fire-breath. If he is one level smaller, his breath won’t reach the block. (I figured that if it were that simple, I would have already tried it, and I probably had. `:-(`)

Comment: Also, you can’t get it if it’s on the lava because touching the lava doesn’t just do damage or knock you down a size, it instantly kills, regardless of how big you are.

Comment: @Synetech inc. - One of the LP's I watched the guy grabbed an item that was sitting on lava by landing on the item (which stopping his falling as an animation played, I think it was a mushroom or something) and then jumping immediately after. If this is supposed to be possible or if he was exploiting a glitch I don't know. Of course, if you can't destroy the block it doesn't really matter anyway. Oh well...

Comment: It probably was a glitch or perhaps using the super-slow trick in an emulator (like they use for speed-runs) because on the console at normal speed, getting even close to the lava turns you around and sinks you. In fact, I’m fairly certain that items sink in the lava! So even if it were possible you would need super-human timing (or just super-slow it in an emulator).